# Is it possible to stop a Server response from the client which is receiving it

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, request

My scenario is something like this:

1. There are multiple cards on the view on a web/mobile app.
2. On the opening of a card, a GET call is made to a server, with a specific URL of some encrypted file.
3. The server makes a request to the URL, pipes it to a decryption function and pipes the final result as response to the client.
   request(url).pipe(decrypt).pipe(response);
4. Now there is a possibility that the user can click on a card and swipe to the next card, and to the next until the last card.

In this case, if there are 5 cards and the user opens the first one and swipes till the 5th then 5 GET calls are sent. But I do not need the response of the cards 1-4 as the user is currently on 5th card.

Is there a way to stop the Calls in progress as the files of those cards are no longer being rendered?

Comment: Could you add the client-code for sending the requests? And what request-lib are you using node node to make the remote request?

Comment: On the client it is simply a video tag, the URL is given as a source to it.
On Node I am using the request module.